# Insert Records if not exist and then update with identity in one query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables.

```
create table Sales 
(CustomerKey int
,ProductKey int
,CustomersProductsKey int
,SalesAmount decimal(19,4))

Create Table CustomersProducts
(CustomersProductsKey int IDENTITY(1,1),
CustomerKey int,
ProductKey int,
Attribute1 int,
Attribute2 varchar(max))
```

Currently when I add data to the sales table, I need to insert any new customerkey productkey combinations into the CustomersProducts table and then update the sales table with the resulting CustomersProductsKey identity value.  This works.

Is there anyway that I can do this in one step?  I don't know if a Merge can do an insert and update on the same if not matched step.

I also could be just looking at this the wrong way as well.

Thanks,

EDIT:

As you can imagine, the fact that I need to use a surrogate key is part of the design.  It's needed for a BO report.   Otherwise there would really be no need for CustomersProductsKey at all.

Answer (score 0):

If add only one step to make it work, 
I think we need create a another table and create trigger on the new table and  CustomersProducts

```
create table CustomersSalesProducts
(CustomerKey int
,ProductKey int
,SalesAmount decimal(19,4)
,Attribute1 int
,Attribute2 varchar(max))


create trigger test1 on CustomersSalesProducts After Insert
as 
begin 
  insert Sales select CustomerKey , ProductKey , 0, SalesAmount from inserted    
  insert CustomersProducts select CustomerKey , ProductKey , Attribute1, Attribute2 from inserted     
end 
go

create trigger test2 on CustomersProducts after insert
as 
begin 
  Update Sales set CustomersProductsKey = inserted.CustomersProductsKey
  from inserted , Sales 
  where inserted.CustomerKey = Sales.CustomerKey
    and inserted.ProductKey = Sales.ProductKey     
end 
go
```

Test Script：

```
insert CustomersSalesProducts select 3,3,300,3,'Attribute2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, no triggers allowed.